# When i click edit button Dropdown value is not display using mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

When i click edit button. the drop down value is not coming but in  `ViewBag.DomainID` value is present but it is not displaying. it shows `The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int64' type to the 'System.Int32' type is not valid.`

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
        [MyExceptionHandler]
        public ActionResult EditModules(int id)
        {
            EditDomain_Bind();
            userType type = new userType();
            var ModID = type.GetEditRoleModulesViews(id).Find(Emp => Emp.ModuleID == id);
            int domainID = ModID.DomainID;
            AccountContext db = new AccountContext();
            string selected = (from sub in db.domain
                               where sub.DomainID == domainID
                               select sub.DomainName).First();
            ViewBag.DomainID = new SelectList(db.domain, "DomainID", "DomainName", selected);

            return View(ModID);
        }
```

Cs.HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                <label class="form-label" for="exampleInput">Domain Name</label>
                                @Html.DropDownList("DomainID")
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.DomainID, null, new { @style = "color: red" })
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
```

Models:

```
public DbSet<Domain> domain { get; set; }
    public class Domain
    {
        [Key]
        public int DomainID { get; set; }      
        public string DomainName { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Does the datatypes of you db are the same than your model?

Comment: @PranayRana check my pic

Comment: @mjwills  https://ibb.co/kpp35G  check it

Comment: value is present in the string Selected @mjwills

Comment: https://ibb.co/fSifkG   @mjwills

Comment: @IvinRaj you could have just googled and found the solution in the first result itself. I highly recommend you to put at least 10 min to research on the issue.

Comment: okay sir sure @Kumar_Vikas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have defined `DomainID` as:

```
public int DomainID { get; set; }
```

in C#, but it is a `bigint` (i.e. `long`) in the database. Thus instead you need to use:

```
public long DomainID { get; set; }
```

And change all other `int` `DomainID` references as well. Such as:

```
long domainID = ModID.DomainID;
```

Comment: working sir thanks

Comment: i need one help dropdown get ID value only ..i want to get DomainName in dropdownlist

Comment: I would suggest creating a new question for that @IvinRaj .